# disabling evil auto copying of selection to clipboard on frame focus

Tags: evil, clipboard

I'm seeing interesting behavior when I try to copy text between other applications and emacs on arch linux, when using evil-mode.

Whenever I have a region selected in emacs, and then click to focus chrome, the region selected is my clipboards contents. I actually only want my region copy'd to my clipboard when I yank.

Also whenever I copy text in chrome, and then focus my emacs window, If I already have a region selected in emacs, that region is now what `evil-paste-after` produces. I expect my copied text from chrome to be pasted, not the region I happen to have selected.
If I have no visually selected region in emacs, then then my next `evil-paste-after` is actually my copy from chrome.

I've seen others remark about `mouse-drag-copy-region` and have the line
`(setq mouse-drag-copy-region nil)` set in my config. This setting seemingly works for me when I'm not using evil-mode. But with evil-mode enabled, my mouse selections end up copying to the clipboard.

I believe [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2624/how-to-disable-copy-on-selection-with-evil-mode-mac-24-4) may solve my issue if I can alter it to be for my platform, instead of OSX

These questions also may be related

- [How to disable emacs evil selection auto copies to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127009/how-to-disable-emacs-evil-selection-auto-copies-to-clipboard/23254728#23254728)
- [Pasting in evil-mode when there's an active selection copies the selection](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9344/pasting-in-evil-mode-when-theres-an-active-selection-copies-the-selection)